# UICollectionView cell reuse causing problems even after taking steps

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I know this question has been asked many times.

I'm using a `UICollectionView` with custom cells which have a few properties, most important being an array of `UISwitch`'s and and array of `UILabel`'s. As you can guess, when I scroll, the labels overlap and the switches change state. I have implemented the method of `UICollectionViewCell` `prepareForReuse` in which I empty these arrays and reset the main label text.

I have tried to combine solutions from different answers and I have reached a point where my labels are preserved, but the state of my switches in the cells isn't. My next step was to create an array to preserve the state before removing the switches and then set the on property of a newly created switch to a value of this array at an index. This works, until after I scroll very fast and switches in cells which were not selected previously become selected(or unselected). This is creating a huge problem for me.

This is my collectionView `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("pitanjeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PitanjeCell

        // remove views previously created and create array to preserve the state of switches
       var selectedSwitches: [Bool] = []

       for item: UIView in cell.contentView.subviews {
            if (item.isKindOfClass(UILabel) && !item.isEqual(cell.tekstPitanjaLabel)){
                item.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            if (item.isKindOfClass(UISwitch)){
                selectedSwitches.append((item as! UISwitch).on)
                item.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }

            // get relevant data needed to place cells programmatically
            cell.tekstPitanjaLabel.text = _pitanja[indexPath.row].getText()
            let numberOfLines: CGFloat = CGFloat(cell.tekstPitanjaLabel.numberOfLines)
            cell.setOdgovori(_pitanja[indexPath.row].getOdgovori() as! [Odgovor])
            var currIndex: CGFloat = 1
            let floatCount: CGFloat = CGFloat(_pitanja.count)
            let switchConstant: CGFloat = 0.8
            let switchWidth: CGFloat = cell.frame.size.width * 0.18
            let heightConstant: CGFloat = (cell.frame.size.height / (floatCount + 2) + (numberOfLines * 4))
            let labelWidth: CGFloat = cell.frame.size.width * 0.9

            for item in _pitanja[indexPath.row].getOdgovori() {

                // create a switch
                let odgovorSwitch: UISwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - (switchWidth * 2)), currIndex * heightConstant , switchWidth, 10))
                odgovorSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(switchConstant, switchConstant)
                let switchValue: Bool = selectedSwitches.count > 0 ? selectedSwitches[Int(currIndex) - 1] : false
                odgovorSwitch.setOn(switchValue, animated: false)

                // cast current item to relevant class
                let obj: Odgovor = item as! Odgovor

                // create a label
                let odgovorLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width / 12), currIndex * heightConstant , labelWidth, 20))
                odgovorLabel.text = obj.getText();
                odgovorLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
                odgovorLabel.font = UIFont(name: (odgovorLabel.font?.fontName)!, size: 15)

                // add to cell
                cell.addSwitch(odgovorSwitch)
                cell.addLabel(odgovorLabel)

                currIndex++
            }

                return cell
    }
```

My custom cell also implements methods `addSwitch` and `addLabel` which add the element to the `contentView` as a `subview`.

Is there any way I can consistently preserve the state of switches when scrolling?

EDIT: As per @Victor Sigler suggestion, I created a bydimensional array like this:

```
var _switchStates: [[Bool]]!
```

I initialized it like this:

```
let odgovori: Int = _pitanja[0].getOdgovori().count
                _switchStates = [[Bool]](count: _pitanja.count, repeatedValue: [Bool](count: odgovori, repeatedValue: false))
```

And I changed my method like this:

```
for item: UIView in cell.contentView.subviews {
            if (item.isKindOfClass(UILabel) && !item.isEqual(cell.tekstPitanjaLabel)){
                item.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            if (item.isKindOfClass(UISwitch)){
                _switchStates[indexPath.row][current] = (item as! UISwitch).on
                current++
                selectedSwitches.append((item as! UISwitch).on)
                item.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
```

And in the end:

```
 let switchValue: Bool = _switchStates.count > 0 ? _switchStates[indexPath.row][Int(currIndex) - 1] : false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it!

In the end I implemented this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var current: Int = 0
        var cell = cell as! PitanjeCell
        for item: UISwitch in cell.getOdgovoriButtons() {
            if(current == _switchStates[0].count) { break;}
            _switchStates[indexPath.row][current] = (item).on
            current++
        }
    }
```

In this function I saved the state.

This in combo with prepareForReuse:

```
public override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.tekstPitanjaLabel.text = nil
        self._odgovoriButtons.removeAll()
        self._odgovoriLabels.removeAll()
        self._odgovori.removeAll()
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
```

Finally did it!

Answer (score 1):

First of all as you said in your question regarding the default behavior of the cell in the `UICollectionView` you need to save the state of each cell, in your case with the `UISwitch`, but you need to preserve the state in a local property, not in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method because this method is calles every time a cell is going to be reused.

So first declare the array where you going to save the state of the `UISwitch`'s outside this function, something like this:

```
var selectedSwitches: [Bool] = []
```

Or you can declare it and then in your `viewDidLoad` instantiate it, it's up to you, I recommend you instantiate it in your `viewDidLoad` and only declare it as a property like this:

```
var selectedSwitches: [Bool]!
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the state of your `UISwitch`'s always of course preserving when change to `on` or `off`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Each of my cells has multiple switches. It is unclear to me should I leave my current code in cellForItemAtIndexPath namely this:if (item.isKindOfClass(UISwitch)){
                selectedSwitches.append((item as! UISwitch).on)
                item.removeFromSuperview()
            }

Or should I remove it and try to save the state elsewhere?

Comment: I don't understand very well what you said, please be more clear

Comment: Where do I save state to this property? Do I need to remove everything from the array each time cellForItemAtIndexPath is called?

Comment: I understand, in your case you need a bidiminsenional array to achieve this and in the position `[0][0]` you have the state of the cell with `indexPath.row == 0` and the `UISwitch` 0 , and go on. I going to update my answer

Comment: I have just tried this. I will edit the question with my code. Please help if you can, this is driving me crazy.